# Are the level 7 benefits of a Lore Oracle's Whirlwind Lesson revelation permanent?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, oracle

An oracle with the [Lore mystery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo-oracle-mysteries/lore/) can pick the *Whirlwind Lesson* revelation:

> Whirlwind Lesson (Ex): You can quickly browse through a magical tome or manual, gaining its benefits with only a single 8-hour study session (rather than the usual 48 hours over a period of 6 days). At 7th level, you may allow another character to join in your study; both of you gain the full benefit of having read the book. At 15th level, you may share your whirlwind lesson with a number of characters equal to your oracle level. The benefits to you are permanent, whereas your students gain the tome or manual’s benefits for a number of days equal to your Charisma modifier but then forget what they have learned.

It is explicit that when shared with a group of people (the 15th level ability), the benefits are temporary. But what about the 7th level ability, when sharing the full benefit with one other character?

I am confused by the last sentence (*"The benefits to you..."*).  Which benefits, specifically?  Maybe it only refers to the 15th level ability, however maybe it instead applies to both the 7th and 15th level abilities. I suspect that the pluralization of "students" implies only the 15th level ability, but I want to be certain. But if it applies to both, then that would mean that the 7th level ability (i.e., benefits to one other character) is also temporary.

**Does the other character permanently gain the benefit, or just temporarily?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s impossible to say. Rules-as-written, the “temporary rule” applies to your “students”—but nothing in the feat defines anyone as your students, so... I guess they apply to nobody?

Being less pedantic, it’s pretty clear that the group you share the book with are supposed to be considered students. The question is whether or not the one person if the 7th-level version is. The sentence with the temporary rule follows the 15th-level version which follows the 7th-level version, and they are all in one paragraph. There is no indication, through sentence or paragraph structure, or punctuation, or verbiage, how “far back” that sentence is supposed to indicate. The use of “students” appears to have been an attempt to indicate this, but since those aren’t defined anywhere, we’re left guessing. The text doesn’t even use something like “teach” which would implicitly define those taught as students. It’s basically hopeless to try to be certain here.

All that said, there is some circumstantial evidence that “students” refers to everyone not you, in the 7th- and the 15th-level versions. For one thing, the 15th-level version is not offered as an optional—it would be very weird to lose a potent ability when you level up. And for another, it would be extremely powerful to double the effects of every tome—that is a very unlikely ability to have in the game.

Answer (score 2):

**A session shared with one character is permanent for both participants; a session shared with more than one other character is temporary (for them).**

The rules as written, and in a plain English reading of the text, make a distinction between the two types of session. In the first case where a lesson is shared with one other character, you both get "the full benefit" of the book; no mention of impermanence is made. In the second case, the lesson only lasts a few days for the other participants.

If the intention was that the text about the effect being temporary applied to both kinds of session, it should have been arranged differently. Most likely it would have been written:

> At 7th level, you may allow another character to join in your study; both of you gain the benefit of having read the book. The benefits to you are permanent, whereas your student gains the tome or manual’s benefits for a number of days equal to your Charisma modifier but then forgets what they have learned. At 15th level, you may share your whirlwind lesson with a number of characters equal to your oracle level.

That there are two separate statements about how the benefits are received, and the first case explicitly calls out that both participants get the "full benefit" as opposed to the unqualified temporary "benefits" in the second case, supports quite strongly the argument that these are two distinct cases. You're hardly getting the "full benefit" of a *Manual* or *Tome* if it wears off after a few days.